# Errors in sstatic.net CSS file

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

In http://sstatic.net/mso/all.css?v=4905, there are a number of errors, according to Firefox:

- Expected 'important' but found 'ie7'
- Error in parsing value for 'max-height'. Declaration dropped.
- Unknown property 'border-radius'. Declaration dropped.
- Unknown property 'zoom'. Declaration dropped.
- Error in parsing value for 'filter'. Declaration dropped.
- The 'charCode' property of a keydown event should not be used. The value is meaningless.
- Unknown property 'word-break'. Declaration dropped.
- The 'charCode' property of a keyup event should not be used. The value is meaningless.

Comment: Oh good, it's not an **Opera** issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a lot of the css rules we use are browser specific by design.

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsstatic.net%2Fmso%2Fall.css%3Fv%3D4905&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&lang=en

Also, there are some browsers that require some css workarounds for proper behavior, most notably IE7, although there is a very nasty IE8 specific bug with `<pre>` that we have to work around as well.